# What is the best practice when design a bundle of complex view layouts within a Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, view, fragment

I need design a very complex layouts in Fragment. But I only have two strategies now.
First, using a bundle of ViewGroups to organize the view logic together.
Second, using a bundle of Fragments as the child of the MainFragment. But I am worry about the performance, because creating a Fragment is more expensive than creating a view.

Comment: Also Android phones are above 1GHz nowadays, maybe you should just try and investigate whether the speed is too slow. It's not bad to make a slow prototype.

Comment: It depends on the logic behind your complex view. If the logic can be broken down into modules with least dependency, go for `Fragments`. And if not, keep up with `View`s. In this case, using a wise combination of `View`s and `layout`s can address any complicated problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your views need to be in the same Activity, try using [ConstrainLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

According to documentation:

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

Add ConstraintLayout to your app and sync project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0"
}
```

To convert an existing layout to a constraint layout, follow these steps:

1. Open your layout in Android Studio and click the Design tab at the bottom of the editor window.
2. In the Component Tree window, right-click the layout and click Convert layout to ConstraintLayout.
   [image: ConstraintLayout]
   Here's a good tutorial you can read: [ConstraintLayout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9475-constraintlayout-tutorial-for-android-complex-layouts)